# is there a list type in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, data-types

I know there are dynamically sized arrays, but I need a data structure that can remove elements from the middle cheaply. Using pop() with a dynamically sized array should require a shift of every element coming after by one, which would be way too expensive. Is there an industry standard way of doing this?

Alternatively I can switch the element I want to delete with the last element in a dynamic array and then pop() the last element, because the order of my list doesn't matter.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity/13168#13168

Answer (score 2):

This is a library for organizing an unordered key set with delete capability.

https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/UnorderedKeySet

It is an implementation of the Mapped Structs with Delete-enabled Index technique in the SE page Richard linked to.

The library deals with the keys only. Store structs in a mapping to handle additional fields.

Hope it helps.